# Stretch gridview to full screen

Tags: java, android, gridview

My gridview consists of 7 lines. Each cell contains a small image and text. How can I stretch this gridview with 7 lines on the full screen?

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:numColumns="7"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
</GridView>
```

For cell:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >
    </TextView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/image" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I run this, I can achieve stretching of each column by setting an explicit height on the `GridView.

If you want this to be dynamic, I'd suggest setting an explicit height programatically.

Comment: But when I set layout_height for gridView 500dp for example, it produces no result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From research it can act strangely if not done correctly on different devices (perhaps mine worked by luck).

Comment: I suggest setting a minimum height on the columns too. It is a strange one.